# Only show 3 select field rows at once (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I'm trying to only show 3 of the select field rows at once.  i.e. I'd like Celebrity, Entertainment and Fad to be displayed and then the user can scroll down / up to select what they want.  Right now, when someone hits the select field, roughly 8 rows show up.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<%= f.select(:category, options_for_select([['Celebrity', 1], ['Entertainment', 2], ['Fad', 3], ['Funny', 4], ['Person', 5], ['Pets', 6], ['Place', 7], ['Relationship', 8], ['Sports', 9], ['Time', 10], ['Travel', 11], ['Thing', 12], ['Work', 13]], 5), {}, { :class=>"imy", :tabindex => "5", :style=>"width:430px;"}) %>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this job should be done by javascript but not Rails.

try the 2 jquery select plugins below:

1. http://loudev.com/
2. http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#enabledisable

Answer (score 0):

HTML uses the "size" select attribute, most surely the [forms has that attribute as a parameter for the control](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag).

So it should be

```
<%= f.select(:category, options_for_select(...), size: 3 %>
```

Comment: hmm, tried this and can't get it to work.  <%= f.select(:category, options_for_select([['Celebrity', 1], ['Entertainment', 2], ['Fad', 3], ['Funny', 4], ['Person', 5], ['Pets', 6], ['Place', 7], ['Relationship', 8], ['Sports', 9], ['Time', 10], ['Travel', 11], ['Thing', 12], ['Work', 13]], 5), {}, { :class=>"imy", :tabindex => "5", :style=>"width:430px;", size: 3}) %>